# use Insert<T>(T o) with an object type

Tags: c#, .net

I have a method

```
public void Insert<T>(T o) where T : class
{
            c.Set<T>().Add(o);
}
```

I need to use it with an object type

```
object x = ....

r.Insert(x);
```

but since it's an object `T == object`, but I need it to be the `x.GetType()` type

anybody knows how to do this ?

Comment: can you provide bigger snippet of what you want to achive?

Comment: for instance, why is x an object? what would you anticipate x.GetType() to be?

Comment: @Pharabus x.GetType() could any of the Entities of my application e.g. Person, User, Role etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'd basically have to call it via reflection (e.g. using `MethodInfo.MakeGenericMethod`). Generics is about providing *compile-time* type safety, whereas you don't know the type at compile time. Alternatively you can use dynamic typing if you're on C# 4.

Using reflection is a pain in terms of:

- Lack of type safety at compile time, so errors can only be detected in tests (or in production!)
- Performance
- Ease of coding

If you're using C# 4, the dynamic typing solution would be:

```
dynamic d = x;
r.Insert(d);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do it using reflection:

```
var method = r.GetType().GetMethod("Insert").MakeGenericMethod(new[] { x.GetType() });
method.Invoke(r, new[] { x });
```

But that's very inefficient... if you find yourself in a situation where you need to do that, you should probably reconsider your design

If you can, try to provide a non generic version of your method:

```
public void Insert(object o) where T : class
{
    c.Set(o.GetType()).Add(o);
}
```

(you also need a non-generic version of `Set`)

Answer (score 2):

If you know the type, simply cast it:

```
r.Insert((YourType)x);
```

If you don't know it: See the other answers.

Comment: Fixed. Didn't know about it :)

Comment: Or rather `r.Insert(x as YourType)`

Comment: You should use `as` only in a conditional context, i.e. only when you use a different path when the cast didn't work.

Comment: @ja72, why? if the type of x isn't YourType, you will get a null, which will probably cause a `NullReferenceException` somewhere else, making the bug harder to track. If you expect an object to be of a certain type, use a cast, not `as`: that way you will get a meaningful exception (`InvalidCastException`)

Comment: @Thomas - because it is logical that the `Insert()` operation handles the `null` case, and not wherever it is implemented. Do you manually check for `null` before you add an item to a [user-defined] collection, or do you handle it within the add function? Which one sounds simpler and more consistent?

Comment: @ja72: The user defined collection doesn't check for `null`. Why should it? `null` values aren't illegal in collections.

Comment: @Thomas - you just said that passing a `null` will cause a `NullReferenceException` somewhere else, and now you said it is not a problem? So which is it? I say, any `Insert()` operation should be robust to check for nulls, and that casting `(YourType)obj` will throw an exception when it is not necessary.

Comment: @ja72, the previous comment wasn't mine, so I'm not contradicting myself. Anyway, it's still better to get an `InvalidCastException` when you get an object of an unexpected type, rather that handle the case where the added value is null (a null value could be valid, depending on the context). BTW, a cast will also return null if x is null...

Comment: @ja72: Please don't rip things out of their context. @Thomas said, that the `NullReferenceException` is likely to appear **somewhere else** if the programmer assumes, that all elements are of the desired type, but in fact are not. This has nothing to do with an `Insert` not being robust.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the Insert command via reflection in order to specify the type at runtime.

I would add a second overload of the insert method like this:

```
private static readonly MethodInfo setMethod = typeof(WhateverCIs).GetMethod("Set");

public void Insert(object o)
{
    var t = o.GetType();

    var set = setMethod.MakeGenericMethod(new[] { t });
    (set.Invoke(c) as WhateverSetReturns).Add(o);
}
```